# php move_uploaded_file trying to change file name during move

Tags: php, file-upload

I am getting an error when i try and rename a file I am taking in from a html form into a directory using the following code. I need to alter the file name to make it unique by concatenating the `$studyId` onto it.  The error prints out the file correctly originalName/studyId.extension. I can move the files into the "videos" folder if I do no concatentation and just use `$_FILES["sonogram"]["name"]` as the second argument for move_uploaded_file there are examples on php.net that use this syntax where you choose what your going to name the uploaded file so I am assuming its something silly.  I should mention I am on a windows system.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$pathParts = pathinfo($_FILES["sonogram"]["name"]);
$file = $pathParts['filename'] . '/'. strval($studyId) . '.'. $pathParts['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sonogram"]["tmp_name"],"videos/". $file);
```

Comment: Can you post a var_dump() of $pathParts and $file? Without seeing what the code produces, we can only guess at the reason. As well, make sure that the `videos/$pathParts[filename]` subdir actually exists and is writeable before moving things into it. m_u_f() will NOT create directories for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By concatening '/', you are telling Windows that it's in another directory. So, the file is trying to be moved to, example, "videos/filename/studyId.mp4". Which means the directory "filename" should exist. If you want to use another directory, use `mkdir`, or, changed the slash to an underscore or some other character.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to move the file in a folder which probably doesn't exist.
Your code would try to move the file to this location (with `filename.txt` and 1234 as `$sudId`):

```
videos/filename/1234.txt
```

whereas the directory `filename` probably doesn't exist in videos.

You could however create it first:

```
$pathParts = pathinfo($_FILES["sonogram"]["name"]);
$file = $pathParts['filename'] . '/'. strval($studyId) . '.'. $pathParts['extension'];
mkdir('videos/'.$pathParts['filename'],0777,TRUE);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["sonogram"]["tmp_name"],"videos/". $file);
```